# Foreign Key - how to solve this in template - django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i have 3 models:

`Book`, `Topiccenter` and `EntryBook`.

these are model definitions:

```
class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.TextField()
  language = models.TextField()

class Topiccenter(models.Model):
  title = models.TextField():
  description = models.TextField()

class EntryBook(models.Model):
  book = models.ForeignKey(Book,related_name="b_entries")
  topiccenter = models.ForeignKey(Topiccenter,related_name="tc_books")
```

Now I am in Topiccenter `T`. and i search for books and get all books in DB. As you see, each book can be in multiple topiccenters.

What i want to do is, in the search result, i want to show whether each book is contained in current Topiccenter or not:

I will take all books `books = Book.objects.all()` and the current topiccenter as `tc` and render them to template and in template,

```
{% for book in books %}
  {% for entry in book.b_entries.all %}
    {% if entry.topiccenter.id == tc.id %}
      already in this Topiccenter
    {% else %}
      add to this topiccenter
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

but the problem is that one book is in two topiccenters and in template i am getting both `already in this Topiccenter` and `add to this topiccenter` which is nonesense. How can i repair my logic so that I can check if the book in this current topiccenter, and if not, show them `add` button

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See how you can move it to the view. In this case, get all books associated with the `tc` and send that in the context.

Now, the template logic would be:

```
{% for book in books %}
  {% if book in tc_books %}
    already in this Topiccenter
  {% else %}
      add to this topiccenter
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where (in the view)

```
tc_books = Books.objects.filter(b_entries__topiccenter = tc)
```

and send that in the context

Comment: great man, wondering why i didnot come to this idea.. :) thanks

Comment: A much faster idea would be to get both the books that are in the topic center and the ones that are not in it :)

Comment: @lcfseth, yeah, you r also rihgt

Comment: @icfseth - I agree with you, but if you just want a long list of all the books, with add/already added options, this is better IMO